# º, aka Masculine Ordinal Indicator, Breaking XML Node Creation in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, xml

Here is some PHP code that creates XML nodes from  a MySQL DB call. It works great except the masculine ordinal indicator `º` breaks the code. Any suggestions or tips would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**Code**

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT street FROM Addresses");
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $node = $dom->create_element("marker");
  $newnode = $parnode->append_child($node);
  $newnode->set_attribute("street", $row['street']);
}
```

The code breaks when `$row['street']` has an entry that looks something like `Nº111-E AVENIDA FOO`.

**Expected Result**

```
<markers><marker street="Nº111-E AVENIDA FOO" /></markers>
```

**Actual (Broken) Result**

```
<markers><marker street="N
```

It breaks on the `º`. I've tried using `utf8_encode($row['street'])` and `htmlentities($row['street'])` but neither helped.

**Manually Entering Character**

The curious thing is that if the address is added manually, as follows, the code works well and in fact, the `º` automatically gets converted to its HTML encoding `&#xBA;`.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT street FROM Addresses");
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $node = $dom->create_element("marker");
  $newnode = $parnode->append_child($node);
  $newnode->set_attribute("street", "Nº111-E AVENIDA FOO");
}
```

Result when manually entering `º`:

```
<markers><marker street="N&#xBA;111-E AVENIDA FOO" /></markers>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bah, after posting this, I figured out that the problem was somewhere else. `htmlentities($row['street'])` works just fine.

**Final Code**

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT street FROM Addresses");
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $node = $dom->create_element("marker");
  $newnode = $parnode->append_child($node);
  $newnode->set_attribute("street", htmlentities($row['street']));
}
```

If the mods thinks this is a useless post, please go ahead and delete it. Otherwise, I'll leave it up in case someone else finds it useful.

Comment: Which library are you using here? DOM APIs are supposed to take care of the encoding/decoding.

Comment: `$dom = domxml_new_doc("1.0");` This is existing code and it looks like someone tried using `$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");` but then changed their mind and commented that out.

Comment: Ah, here's the problem, this site is running PHP 4.4 and it looks like DOMDocument() is a PHP 5 construct.

Comment: @jiminy oh, there's your problem :-) Upgrade?

Comment: 'running' on php4.4 ?? in **2014** ?

Comment: lol, yeah, sssh, obviously, we've got some upgrading to do! Fun!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in the library you're using. Tested with the PHPs DOM extension it works fine:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$markers = $dom->appendChild($dom->createElement('markers'));
$markers
  ->appendChild($dom->createElement('marker'))
  ->setAttribute('street', 'Nº111-E AVENIDA FOO');

echo $dom->saveXml();
```

Output: https://eval.in/192358

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<markers><marker street="N&#xBA;111-E AVENIDA FOO"/></markers>
```

Comment: Thanks for the assist. I was trying out the wrong spot when testing so when I put `htmlentities` in the right spot, everything is happy again.